# MobX decorators not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, mobx, mobx-react

I'm having trouble getting decorators such as @observable and @computed to work in my project.

Here are my files.

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "heroku-react",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-plugin-syntax-decorators": "^6.13.0",
    "mobx": "^3.1.11",
    "mobx-react": "^4.2.1",
    "react": "^15.5.4",
    "react-dom": "^15.5.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy": "^1.3.4",
    "babel-preset-stage-1": "^6.24.1",
    "react-scripts": "1.0.7"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  }
}
```

App.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import GameBoard from './components/game-board';
import { inject, observer } from 'mobx-react';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <div className="App-header">
        </div>
        <GameBoard />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

.babelrc:

```
{
  "presets": [
    "es2015",
    "react",
    "stage-1"
  ],
  "plugins": ["transform-decorators-legacy"]
}
```

When I add the @observer decorator like so (@observer class App extends Component {...}) before my class declaration I receive this error:

```
Failed to compile
./src/App.js
Syntax error: Unexpected token (7:0)

   5 | import { inject, observer } from 'mobx-react';
   6 | 
>  7 | @observer class App extends Component {
     | ^
   8 |   render() {
   9 |     return (
  10 |       <div className="App">
```

Answer (score 2):

Look like you are using `create-react-app` and didn't make [`eject`](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app#converting-to-a-custom-setup). In order to use decorators you should make it. Or use [custom-react-scripts](https://github.com/kitze/custom-react-scripts) as alternative.

Answer (score 0):

Proper way of installing mobx when you are using `create-react-app` is as follows;

1. `create-react-app ExampleApp`
2. `npm run eject`
3. `npm install --saveDev babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy`
4. Update your .babelrc file as it is right now (with transform-decorators-legacy)
5. `npm install --save mobx mobx-react`

That should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I don't use 'stage-1' but I have the following plugins

```
"plugins": [
    "transform-decorators-legacy",
    "transform-class-properties"
  ]
```

and these dependencies in package.json

```
"babel": "^6.23.0",
"babel-loader": "^7.1.2",
```

And as you try different configs make sure the public/packs folder get cleared out. I run into some trouble with cached files.